# Llenar matriz aleatoriamente sin repetir números

Tags: c#

Quisiera aprender cómo llenar esta matriz de 10x10 pero sin que se repitan los números, este es mi código

```
int posi = 0, posj = 0, mayor = 0;//declaracion de variables para la posicion y el numero mayor

        Console.WriteLine("Matriz de 10*10\n");

        int[,] matriz = new int[11, 11];  //Creacion de la matriz de 10*10 (10filas, 10 columnas)
        Random aleatorio = new Random();//declaracion del random para llenar la matriz 

        //se recorre la matriz para asignar los valores
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                matriz[i, j] = aleatorio.Next(0, 100);
            }


        // se recorre nuevamente para leer sus valores y validar cual es mayor y capturar su respectiva posicion
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    if (matriz[i, j] > mayor)//si matriz en la posicion i,j es > mayor
                    {
                        mayor = matriz[i, j]; // a mayor -> el valor que hay en la posicion i, j
                        posi = i; // a la posicion i -> i
                        posj = j;// a la posicion j -> j
                    }
                    //imprimir matriz  
                    Console.Write(matriz[i, j].ToString() + " ");
                }
            Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: recorre la matriz por cada numero aleatorio nuevo que le metas, con la verificacion si el elemento se repite `if (nuevoarray[i][j] != array[i][j]) array.add(randomelement);`

Comment: Create una lista de numeros, cada vez que generas un numero compruebas si esta en la lista, si esta vuelves a generar un numero y comprobar... y si no esta lo metes en el array y en la lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un HasSet que que almacene inicialmente los 100 numeros de forma aleatoria y posteriormente volcarlos a la matriz, de esta forma tu código queda optimizado al realizar un solo recorrido de la matriz

algo como

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int columnas = 4;
        int filas = 4;
        int maxvalues = filas * columnas;
        int[,] matris = new int[filas, columnas]; 
        HashSet<Int32> numeros = new HashSet<Int32>();

        Random ran = new Random();

        while(numeros.Count < maxvalues)
        {
            numeros.Add(ran.Next(maxvalues));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(numeros.Count);
        foreach(int n in numeros)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

De esta forma no tienes que hacer una funcion de validación para saber si un número ya fue almacenado o no, ya que el HashSet no almacena duplicados, posteriormente recorres el HashSet y lo almacenas en la matriz.
El HashSet es una colección no ordenada que no permite duplicados.

Otra solución alternativa puede ser

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int filas = 4;
        int columnas = 4;
        int maxvalues = filas * columnas;

        ArrayList numerosOrdenados = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList numerosDesordenados = new ArrayList();
        int[,] matriz = new int[filas, columnas];

        //Se llenan los numeros de forma ordenada
        for (int i = 0; i < maxvalues; i++)
        {
            numerosOrdenados.Add(i);
        }

        Random ran = new Random();

        //Se desorganizan
        while(numerosOrdenados.Count > 0)
        {
            int index = ran.Next(numerosOrdenados.Count);
            numerosDesordenados.Add(numerosOrdenados[index]);
            numerosOrdenados.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        //llenar matriz
        for(int i = 0; i < numerosDesordenados.Count; i++)
        {
            int f = i / filas;
            int c = i % filas;

            matriz[f, c] = (int)numerosDesordenados[i];

        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: lo intentó asi pero me trae son solo ceros, //se recorre la matriz para asignar los valores
            var numeros = new HashSet<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    while (numeros.Count < 100)
                    {
                        numeros.Add(aleatorio.Next(0, 100));
                    }
                    //matriz[i, j] = aleatorio.Next(0, 100);
                }

Comment: En tu primer ejemplo solo metes los números en el `HashSet<Int32>`, pero luego, no pasa nada más que imprimirlos y no sabes si se han repetido o no. A lo mejor para que el ejemplo quede más completo puedes complementar la parte de llenar la matriz ;)

Comment: @Flxtr, El HashSet es una estructura de datos que no almacena números repetidos, en caso que la función random genere el mismo número, el HashSet solo lo almacenara una única vez, por lo tanto se garantiza que no hay números repetidos.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta un algoritmo.. el que busque los elementos repetidos de la matriz..

pero primero

```
int[,] matriz = new int[11, 11];
```

es de 10X10?? entonces porque la defines de 11X11???

vamos a suponer.. que reemplazamos esto...

```
matriz[i, j] = aleatorio.Next(0, 100);
```

por algo asi..

```
NuevoNumero = aleatorio.Next(0,100)
```

y despues.. llamamos a una funcion de control

```
bool ControlarMatriz(int[,] matriz, int NuevoNumero)
```

y esa funcion.. lo que hace.. es recorrer toda la matriz y retornar, `true` si esta repetido y `false` si no esta repetido.

entonces.. nos faltaría solo una cosa.. mientras esa función devuelva `false`, no guardamos nada en la matriz.. y si devuelve `true`, lo guardamos...

Comment: Entiendo que cuando es 10x 10 le adiciono uno de mas para no desbordarla, eso lo adquirí en los vectores unidimensionales.ademas cuando hablas de funciones no me es claro, hoy apenas recibí la primera clase de funciones y procedimientos jejej

Comment: No deberia desbordarse. Porque piensas eso?

Comment: debe ser errores de primiparo, jeje, ademas algo que nunca he usado es el bool, y veo que es muy util