# ¿Cómo hacer que no se repitan los números en una matriz?

Tags: java

Tengo una matriz a la cual pedimos por teclado el tamaño de filas y columnas, luego la relleno con números aleatorios del 0 al 100.

En otro bucle quiero hacer que si se repiten los números se vuelvan a hacer aleatorio querría hacerlo comparando cada posición.(dividir el trabajo uno para rellenar la matriz y luego en otra parte comprobar)

Os dejo mi código:

```
      Random aleatorio=new Random();
    int maximo=100;
    int minimo=0;
     int numeroAleatorio=aleatorio.nextInt((maximo-minimo)+1)+minimo;
  byte filas;
 byte columnas;
    System.out.println("Dime cuantas filas quieres para matriz");
 filas=Byte.parseByte(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Dime cuantas columnas quieres para la matriz");
 columnas=Byte.parseByte(sc.nextLine());
 int [][]matriz=new int [filas][columnas];
 int contadorFila=0;
 int contadorColumna=0;
 int[][] comprueboAleatorio=new int [filas][columnas];
  int probando=0;//Primera parte para rellenar
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            matriz[i][j]=numeroAleatorio;
             numeroAleatorio=aleatorio.nextInt((maximo-minimo)+1)+minimo;
        }
    }
```

para comprobar

```
    for (int i = 0; i < filas*columnas+1; i++) {
         numeroAleatorio=aleatorio.nextInt((maximo-minimo)+1)+minimo;

        for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
            contadorColumna=0;
            for (int k = 0; k < matriz[j].length-1; k++) {
                contadorColumna++;
                if (matriz[j][k]==matriz[j][contadorColumna]) {
                    matriz[j][k]=comprueboAleatorio[j][k];

                }
                if (contadorColumna==columnas-1) {
                    contadorColumna=0;
                } 
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: La probabilidad de que esto no termine nunca es altisima.. mejor ubicar los 100 numeros y despues mezclarlos ;)

Comment: Eso hago los dos primeros for es para rellenar aleatoriamente

Comment: Hay una [pregunta parecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92477/llenar-matriz-aleatoriamente-sin-repetir-n%C3%BAmeros) ya en el sitio

Comment: Consideor que una buena alternativa es tomar en cuenta que al memoneto de elegir el rango de numeros a de manera aleatorea, este debe ser alterado de acuerdo a los numeros que ya se han dispuesto, de esta forma evitas que estos se vuelan a reiterar.

Comment: Como se haría aun sigo intentandolo pero cada vez me alejo menos o eso creo